# Experimentally determining the probability of a binomial experiment

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have a binomial experiment $X$ with probability $p$, and I want to experimentally determine $p$ to within an error $\epsilon$ by averaging the result of $X$ over multiple runs. Is the following a valid way to determine how many times to run $X$?

Let $X_n = X + X + ... + X$ ($n$ times) and $Y_n = \frac{1}{n}X_n$. The mean and std. dev. of $Y_n$ are:

$$
\mu Y_n = \mu (\frac{1}{n}X_n) = \frac{1}{n} \mu X_n = \frac{1}{n} (n\cdot \mu X) = \mu X
$$
$$
\sigma^2 Y_n = \sigma^2( \frac{1}{n}X_n ) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sigma^2(X_n) = \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot n p(1-p) = \frac{1}{n}p(1-p)
$$

If we choose $n$ large enough so that $3\sigma(Y_n) \le \epsilon$ there will be a 99.7% chance that the average of the runs will be within $\epsilon$ of $p$. Using $p(1-p) \le 1/4$ yields the inequality:

$$
\frac{9}{4\epsilon^2} \le n
$$

Besides whether or not this is correct reasoning, I'd also like to know what the standard methodology is in this case. For instance, once you have determined a value for $n$, do you just sample $Y_n$ once or is there value in sampling $Y_n$ multiple times (as opposed to just using a larger value of $n$)?

Comment: As for the standard methodology, this is what we would usually call sampling to estimate a population proportion. Here's an example of a textbook approach to it: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat200/node/255

Comment: Ok - so this pretty much validates my approach. The $z^{*}$ is 3 in my case.

Comment: I must admit I find this answer a bit unsatisfactory, because when you say

"If we choose $n$ large enough so that $3\sigma(Y_n) \le \epsilon$ there will be a 99.7% chance that the average of the runs will be within $\epsilon$ of $p$"

there is the implicit idea that $Y_n$ is modeled by a normal distribution, which is in fact a good approximation, but by how much? I feel this leaves the question fundamentally unanswered.

Comment: I just found [this discussion](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/179) about how good the normal distribution approximation is to the binomial distribution (scroll down to the end.) It states that the general rule of thumb is that $n$ is considered sufficiently large enough if both $np \ge 5$ and $n(1-p) \ge 5$. So I guess you could run into trouble if $p$ is really tiny or very, very close to 1, and that's something to take into consideration.